# Using the determinant to find an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am studying maths as a hobby. I have got to the subject of linear algebra and in particular eigenvectors. I know how to find the determinant of a 3 x 3 matrix but am stumped at the following worked example in the text book.

Find the eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues of

$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

If $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector and $\lambda$ the corresponding eigenvalue then:

$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{pmatrix}$ = $\lambda$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{pmatrix}$

So the characteristic equation is

$\begin{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}-\lambda\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\end{vmatrix}=0$

$\Rightarrow \begin{vmatrix}
2-\lambda & -1 & 1\\
0 & 2-\lambda & 0\\
1 & 3 & 2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}= 0$

Expanding the determinant gives

$(2-\lambda)(2-\lambda)(2-\lambda)+1(-1)(2-\lambda)=0$

This is the part I don't understand. When I calculate the determinant I get

$(2-\lambda)(2-\lambda)(2-\lambda) + (2-\lambda)$

Am I misunderstanding the term "expanding the determinant" or am I making some simple mistake somewhere?

Comment: It is a simple mistake, you forgot the minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
2-\lambda & -1 & 1\\
0 & 2-\lambda & 0\\
1 & 3 & 2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=  (2-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
 2-\lambda & 0\\
 3 & 2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} -(-1)\begin{vmatrix}
0  & 0\\
1  & 2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}+1\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 2-\lambda \\
1 & 3 
\end{vmatrix}=
$$
$$
=(2-\lambda)\cdot(2-\lambda)^2+1\cdot 0+1\cdot(-1(2-\lambda))
$$